# R - Merging Two Data.Frames with Row-Level Conditional Variables

Tags: python, mysql, r, merge, dplyr

Short version: I have a slightly trickier than usual merge operation I'd like help optimizing with dplyr or merge. I have a number of solutions already, but these run quite slow over large datasets and I am curious if there exist a faster method in R (or in SQL or python alternatively)

---

I have two data.frames:

1. a asynchronous log of events tied to Stores, and
2. a table that gives more details about the stores in that log.

The issue: Store IDs are unique identifiers for a specific location, but store locations may change ownership from one period to the next (and just for completeness, no two owners may possess the same store at the same time). So when I merge over store level info, I need some sort of conditional that merges store-level info for the correct period.

---

Reproducible Example:

```
# asynchronous log. 
#  t for period. 
#  Store for store loc ID
#  var1 just some variable. 
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  t     = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
  Store = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3),
  var1 =  runif(11,0,1)
)

# Store table
# You can see, lots of store location opening and closing, 
#  StateDate is when this business came into existence
#  Store is the store id from df
#  CloseDate is when this store when out of business
#  storeVar1 is just some important var to merge over
Stores <- data.frame(
  StartDate = c(0,0,0,4,4),
  Store     = c(1,2,3,2,3),
  CloseDate = c(9,2,3,9,9),
  storeVar1 = c("a","b","c","d","e")
)
```

Now, I only want to merge over information in `Store` d.f. to log, if that `Store` is open for business in that period (`t`). `CloseDate` and `StartDate` indicate the last and first periods of this business's operation, respectively. (*For completeness but not too important, with `StartDate` 0 the store existed since before the sample. For `CloseDate` 9 the store hadn't gone out of business at that location by the end of the sample.*)

One solution relies on a period `t` level `split()` and `dplyr::rbind_all()`, e.g.

```
# The following seems to do the trick. 
complxMerge_v1 <- function(df, Stores, by = "Store"){
  library("dplyr")
  temp <- split(df, df$t)
  for (Period in names(temp))(
    temp[[Period]] <- dplyr::left_join(
      temp[[Period]],
      dplyr::filter(Stores, 
                    StartDate <= as.numeric(Period) & 
                    CloseDate >= as.numeric(Period)),
      by = "Store"
    )
  )
  df <- dplyr::rbind_all(temp); rm(temp)
  df
}
complxMerge_v1(df, Stores, "Store")
```

Functionally, this appears to work (haven't come across a significant error yet anyway). However we are dealing with (increasingly usual) billions of rows of log data.

I made a larger reproducible example on sense.io if you'd like to use it for bench-marking. See here: https://sense.io/economicurtis/r-faster-merging-of-two-data.frames-with-row-level-conditionals

---

Two questions:

1. First and foremost, is there another way to approach this problem using similar methods that will run faster?
2. Is there by chance a quick and easy solution in SQL and Python (of which I am not quite as familiar, but could rely on if need be).
3. Also, can you help me articulate this question in a more general, abstract way? Right now I only know how to talk about the problem in context specific terms, but I'd love to be able to talk about these types of issues with more appropriate, but more general programming or data manipulation terminologies.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when creating reproducible example using functions that use a random seed such as `runif`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R, You could take a look at the `data.table::foverlaps` function

```
library(data.table)

# Set start and end values in `df` and key by them  and by  `Store`
setDT(df)[, c("StartDate", "CloseDate") := list(t, t)]      
setkey(df, Store, StartDate, CloseDate)

# Run `foverlaps` function
foverlaps(setDT(Stores), df)
#     Store t       var1 StartDate CloseDate i.StartDate i.CloseDate storeVar1
#  1:     1 1 0.26550866         1         1           0           9         a
#  2:     1 2 0.90820779         2         2           0           9         a
#  3:     1 3 0.94467527         3         3           0           9         a
#  4:     1 4 0.62911404         4         4           0           9         a
#  5:     2 1 0.37212390         1         1           0           2         b
#  6:     2 2 0.20168193         2         2           0           2         b
#  7:     3 1 0.57285336         1         1           0           3         c
#  8:     3 2 0.89838968         2         2           0           3         c
#  9:     3 3 0.66079779         3         3           0           3         c
# 10:     2 4 0.06178627         4         4           4           9         d
# 11:     3 4 0.20597457         4         4           4           9         e
```

Comment: hmmm. On the line `setDT(df)[, c("StartDate", "CloseDate") := .(t, t)]` I get the error: Sorry, it's not clear what my issue is here. 
`Error in [.data.table(setDT(df), , :=(c("StartDate", "CloseDate"),  : 
  RHS of assignment is not NULL, not an an atomic vector (see ?is.atomic) and not a list column.`

Comment: What version of `data.table` you have? Does `setDT(df)[, c("StartDate", "CloseDate") := list(t, t)]` works?

Comment: That's the line causing the error. The version of data.table I am working with is 1.9.4, `data.table_1.9.4`. I reproduced the same error at that sense.io link too

Comment: Did `setDT(df)[, c("StartDate", "CloseDate") := list(t, t)]` work or not? OR `setDT(df)[, ":="(StartDate = t, CloseDate = t)]`

Comment: That does it, I think perhaps an issue with the `.` operator? Doesn't that require plyr?

Comment: No, its `data.table` syntax

Comment: Huh, I wonder why both sessions I tested `setDT(df)[, c("StartDate", "CloseDate") := .(t, t)] ` produced the same error?  ~ as for your alternatives,  `setDT(df)[, c("StartDate", "CloseDate") := list(t, t)]` or `setDT(df)[, ":="(StartDate = t, CloseDate = t)]`, they are only about 126 times as fast as my suggested idea. Thanks!

Comment: You could also try sort `Stores` first and only then run `foverlaps` it could be even faster. Try `setkey(setDT(Stores), Store, StartDate, CloseDate) ; foverlaps(Stores, df)`. You can also try installing the devel version of `data.table` from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) which has a faster version of `foverlaps` (I believe)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your `Stores` data.frame adding `t`-column, which contains all values of `t` for a definite Store and then use `unnest` function from Hadley's `tydir` package to transform it to "long" form.

```
require("tidyr")
require("dplyr")

complxMerge_v2 <- function(df, Stores, by = NULL)    {
  Stores %>% mutate(., t = lapply(1:nrow(.), 
                                  function(ii) (.)[ii, "StartDate"]:(.)[ii, "CloseDate"]))%>%
    unnest(t) %>% left_join(df, ., by = by)
}

complxMerge_v2(df, Stores)
# Joining by: c("t", "Store")
#    t Store       var1 StartDate CloseDate storeVar1
# 1  1     1 0.26550866         0         9         a
# 2  1     2 0.37212390         0         2         b
# 3  1     3 0.57285336         0         3         c
# 4  2     1 0.90820779         0         9         a
# 5  2     2 0.20168193         0         2         b
# 6  2     3 0.89838968         0         3         c
# 7  3     1 0.94467527         0         9         a
# 8  3     3 0.66079779         0         3         c
# 9  4     1 0.62911404         0         9         a
# 10 4     2 0.06178627         4         9         d
# 11 4     3 0.20597457         4         9         e

require("microbenchmark")
# I've downloaded your large data samples
df <- read.csv("./df.csv")
Stores <- read.csv("./Stores.csv")

microbenchmark(complxMerge_v1(df, Stores), complxMerge_v2(df, Stores), times = 10L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                       expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# complxMerge_v1(df, Stores) 9501.217 9623.754 9712.8689 9681.3808 9816.8984 9886.5962    10
# complxMerge_v2(df, Stores)  532.744  539.743  567.7207  561.9635  588.0637  636.5775    10
```

Here are step-by-step results to make the process clear.

```
Stores_with_t <- 
  Stores %>% mutate(., t = lapply(1:nrow(.), 
                                  function(ii) (.)[ii, "StartDate"]:(.)[ii, "CloseDate"]))
#   StartDate Store CloseDate storeVar1                            t
# 1         0     1         9         a 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
# 2         0     2         2         b                      0, 1, 2
# 3         0     3         3         c                   0, 1, 2, 3
# 4         4     2         9         d             4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
# 5         4     3         9         e             4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

# After that `unnest(t)`

Stores_with_t_unnest <- 
  with_t %>% unnest(t)
#    StartDate Store CloseDate storeVar1 t
# 1          0     1         9         a 0
# 2          0     1         9         a 1
# 3          0     1         9         a 2
# 4          0     1         9         a 3
# 5          0     1         9         a 4
# 6          0     1         9         a 5
# 7          0     1         9         a 6
# 8          0     1         9         a 7
# 9          0     1         9         a 8
# 10         0     1         9         a 9
# 11         0     2         2         b 0
# 12         0     2         2         b 1
# 13         0     2         2         b 2
# 14         0     3         3         c 0
# 15         0     3         3         c 1
# 16         0     3         3         c 2
# 17         0     3         3         c 3
# 18         4     2         9         d 4
# 19         4     2         9         d 5
# 20         4     2         9         d 6
# 21         4     2         9         d 7
# 22         4     2         9         d 8
# 23         4     2         9         d 9
# 24         4     3         9         e 4
# 25         4     3         9         e 5
# 26         4     3         9         e 6
# 27         4     3         9         e 7
# 28         4     3         9         e 8
# 29         4     3         9         e 9

# And then simple `left_join`

left_join(df, Stores_with_t_unnest)
# Joining by: c("t", "Store")
# t Store          var1 StartDate CloseDate storeVar1
# 1  1     1 0.26550866         0         9         a
# 2  1     2 0.37212390         0         2         b
# 3  1     3 0.57285336         0         3         c
# 4  2     1 0.90820779         0         9         a
# 5  2     2 0.20168193         0         2         b
# 6  2     3 0.89838968         0         3         c
# 7  3     1 0.94467527         0         9         a
# 8  3     3 0.66079779         0         3         c
# 9  4     1 0.62911404         0         9         a
# 10 4     2 0.06178627         4         9         d
# 11 4     3 0.20597457         4         9         e
```